# GPS provider security exception

Tags: android, gps, user-permissions

What is the correct way to fix if checking the status of GPS provider throws SecurityException by request permissions in manifest file?

Answer (score 2):

In your Manifest add lines below:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Please have a look to:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#Permissions

To access device features as Camera, GPS, ... you need to request permissions. If permissions is not requested then a SecurityException is thrown.

Comment: I think that coarse location and fine location have not any relation with security, they are needed to describe precision

Comment: Is `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` also needed? or it will also work only with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`?